# Find the value of integral $\int^{2\pi}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Find the value of integral $$\int^{2\pi}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor dx$$

$\lfloor x \rfloor = x-\{x\}$ and $0\leq \{x\}<1$

for $0\leq x<\cot(1),\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor = 0$ and for $\cot (1)\leq x<2\pi,\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor  = 0$

but i want go further for negative interval of $x,$ could some help with me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int^{2\pi}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor dx\\=
\int^{2\pi}_{0}\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor dx+\int^{0}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor dx=$$
$$\int^{0.642}_{0}(+1) dx+\int^{0.642}_{2\pi}(0)+\int^{0}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor dx=$$
$$0.642(+1)+0+\int^{-0.458}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor dx+\int^{0}_{-0.458}\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor dx=\\
0.642(+1)+0+\int^{-0.458}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}(+2) dx+\int^{0}_{-0.458}(+1)dx=\\0.642(+1)+0+(+2)\times(-0.458-(-\frac{\pi}{2}))+(+1)\times(0-(-0.458)$$

remark$$\cot^{-1}(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}=1.57.. 
\\\cot^{-1}(-0.458)=2\\
\cot^{-1}(-\frac{\pi}{2})=2.575\\
0 <x<-0.458 \to \lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor=1\\
-0.458 <x<-\frac{\pi}{2} \to \lfloor \cot^{-1}(x)\rfloor=2$$

[image]

Comment: Should it not $\displaystyle \int^{2\pi}_{0}\lfloor \cot^{-1}(x) \rfloor dx = \int^{\cot 1}_{0}1dx+\int^{2\pi}_{\cot 1}0 dx = \cot 1$

Comment: yes . you are right ,I' correct it